# How to keep N latest values for key in kafka topic using kafka streams

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I use kafka streams (kafka-streams-scala library, version 2.2.0).

I need to keep a few recent values for key in kafka topic using kafka streams. I use it for the enrichment of another stream. So I need something like KTable or GlobalKTable, but they keep only one value.

I figured out one possible way to do this: creating stream and mutable Map, and then using `stream.foreach` to keep tracking of N recent values for each key.

```
val stream: KStream[String, GenericRecord] = builder.stream[String, GenericRecord]("topicName")

val map = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, List[MyObject]]

stream.foreach((k, v) =>  {
  //update map
})
```

my question is if there is a better approach to achieve this - either using streams API or at least without a mutable map.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So I need something like KTable or GlobalKTable, but they keep only one value.

Keep using a `KTable` (or `GlobalKTable`), but use a structured value and/or a collection as "the value". Nothing forces in Kafka forces you to restrict a message value to only a primitive data type (like `Integer` or `String`).

Think: `KStream<UserId, List<ClickEvent>>`.  Here, each message belongs to a particularly user (identified by the key being `UserId`), and each message has list of zero, one, or many `ClickEvent`s associated with that user.  This "just works", you only need to have proper serdes (serializer/deserializer) for the data types you want to use.

For instance, the `CustomStreamTableJoin` example at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples ([direct link to example for v5.2.1](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/CustomStreamTableJoinIntegrationTest.java), which is for Apache Kafka v2.2) uses a [`Pair`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/utils/Pair.java) class to store a tuple in Kafka's message value, and it has its accompanying [`PairSerde`](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.2.1-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/utils/PairSerde.java). The same can be done (and is being done by developers) to store collections of values, like a `List<ClickEvent>`, as you mentioned for your own use case.

> I need to keep a few recent values for key in kafka topic using kafka streams. [...]
>   I figured out one possible way to do this: creating stream and mutable Map, [...]

You shouldn't need to use a `Map`.  The key is already available in the Kafka message, so you only need a List-like data type for the message value.

> or at least without a mutable map.

You don't need to (and shouldn't) use a mutable data structure unless there is a specific reason, which I don't think there is in your use case.  When a new message is being processed and the corresponding output is stored in the `KTable`, then whatever was stored in the table for that key will be overwritten -- so using an immutable data structure as the message value is totally fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it correct that it will work only if messages are being produced to a topic as <UserId, List<ClickEvent>? What if messages are produced as <UserId, ClickEvent> and I still need to keep only 5 latest ClickEvent for each UserId?

Comment: It will work in both cases.  Input messages can be <UserId, ClickEvent>, and output messages (after "most recent values" aggregation) can be <UserId, List<ClickEvent>>.